# what is the difference between DisplayDataMember and ItemTemplate and when to use one over the other?

Tags: wpf, combobox

As mentioned in the title, I want to know the difference between DisplayDataMember and ItemTemplate. I tried to use both of them together and I got a comiler error that both cannot be used at the same time. I also want to know when to use one over the other.

I am a newbie. If this is not a good question to ask then please forgive me.

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` allows you to define a property from the Data Items to be shown as a (text only) representation of the Item, whereas `ItemTemplate` allows you to define any arbitrary content, not limited to text.

Comment: @HighCore If I do not mention any of the above then can I get the comboBox to work?

Comment: If you use *none* of them: Yes, your combobox will work (but the items may not look the way you want). I would start by using only `DisplayMemberPath`, and if you find that your items need to look more fancy later on, use `ItemTemplate` instead.

Comment: @Khushi ComboBox will call ToString() on each item. If you override that method you can make it work without DisplayMemberPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayMemberPath` and `ItemTemplate` are two ways for representing data.
First one only lets you allow string representation whereas other lets you customise combobox content as per your need (not only string representation). As error states you can't define both at same time.

Suppose you have TestClass with property say Name.

```
public class TestClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you bind to ItemsSource of your combobox with collection of objects of this class.

**Without DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"/>
```

[image]

**With DisplayMemberPath**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

[image]

**With ItemTemplate**

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Rectangle Margin="15,0,0,0" Fill="Red"
                               Width="10" Height="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

[image]

I hope images are self explanatory. Let me know if more clarification required.

Also you can achieve `DisplayMemberPath` functionality by simply `overriding ToString()` method on your class since internally it calls ToString() on data item.

```
public class TestClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Name;
   }
}
```